# Remove Core Data database, and re-create it on update

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When I push out a new upgrade to my app that implements a new Core Data entity, my app will crash.

How can I delete the entire Core Data database, and recreate it? I dont care for whats in there, because the data is usually updated when the app loads anyway. Its mainly used for caching, or until it can sync with the server.

Comment: You don't need to delete the entire core data database. Just use core data `Migration` to solve this.

Comment: This one can help http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-migrations-swift-tutorial/

Comment: @Poles migration is an error prone process, a lot of app simple want to drop the tables and start over. I actually do that in Android for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Before initializing your `NSPersistentContainer`:

- Delete your `Model.sqlite` persistant store file
- Delete all other files in the same directory, that contain `.sqlite` in the extension name (`Model.sqlite-shm`, `Model.sqlite-wal`).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use when I instantiate my CoreDataController :

```
private override  init() {
    // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.

    guard let modelURL = NSBundle(forClass:CoreDataController.classForCoder()).URLForResource("YOURAPP", withExtension:"momd") else {
        fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
    }
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL) else {
        fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
    }
    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
    self.managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
    let storeURL = CoreDataController.storeUrl
    do {
        try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(CoreDataController.storeType(), configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
    } catch { //Exception means your database leads to error, so drop it, and create a new one
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(storeURL)
            try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(CoreDataController.storeType(), configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)}
        catch {
            fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
        }

    }
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: Can I call this in my AppDelegate somewhere? Or where is best to call it? I don't have a dedicated CoreDataController. Thanks. I added a migration for the time being, but I think I'll need this in future.

Comment: Personnaly I have a Stand alone classe known as CoreDataController ( and a singleton of it ). All CoreData Related Stuff goes in. That's better than putting all in your app Delegate

Comment: But don't I have to call this before the app fully loads, otherwise I'll get an error about an incompatible db? That's why I was wondering if I could call this in my AppDeleage.